# Need tips in designing a web page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, user-interface

I am little too bad in the UI design in asp.net/html. I am trying to build a new website (just to get back on the skills to develop UI designing) using asp.net/html/visual studio 2012. I have the UI with master pages/css and I am using divs to get the elements in place (I am using  px in css width/height). All looked good when I have my browser in maximized view. When I resize the browser, every thing in the page is so scrambled and I don't even get a scroll bar at the bottom of the browser.

I checked couple of websites and found that I am doing something wrong. When you go to amazon.com and resize your browser, it won't scramble and every thing stays in place. How can I get that? What am I doing wrong? Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have floating elements that aren't cleared. You (perhaps) could fix it by ensuring you are [clearing floating elements](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) in your CSS by using `clear`.

Since you are inexperienced, you'd probably be better served using a boilerplate which will provide you with a good framework to build around. Here are some:

1. [HTML5 Boilerplate for ASP.NET MVC4](http://nuget.org/packages/Html5Boilerplate.Mvc4.Razor/)
2. [Twitter Bootstrap for ASP.NET MVC4](http://nuget.org/packages/twitter.bootstrap.mvc4/)
3. [Amazium](http://www.amazium.co.uk/)
4. or just search for 'bootstrap' on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/)

Comment: ...and possibly could benefit from doing some CSS tutorials.

Comment: Thq for the head start and I am using float in my css. I'll look into your suggestions and I should probably get through it.